# Python code acts strange in apply function from groupby

Tags: python, pandas

Hello I have observed some quite strange pandas/python behavior and would like to understand how this comes to exist.
See the code below. When I call the code without line 2 it does not cause a problem (yes I do not do anything here) and print "hello" once per group. When I call it with this line it prints the correct result, then "hello" and then fails. According to the error message it fails in line 2 with Keyerror 0.

```
1 |def somefunction(group):
2 |  # print(group["Date"][0]) # <- This line causes the problem...
3 |  print("hello")
4 |  return group
5 |
6 |
7 |groups= df_test.groupby(by=["UnitNumber", "Date"]).apply(somefunction)
```

How can this be? I am quite confused why he either fails and then still prints a message or that the program fails in the return because of a print.

In case anyone is fighting with the same problem I fixed it by using the following line instead of line 2.

```
 print(group.iloc[0]["Date"].strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
```

But I still would like to understand why the code above acts so strange. In case there are any know issues i am using Jupyterlabs.

EDIT:
As requested the error message (note that the line numbers are of course different):

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~\scoop\apps\anaconda3\2021.05\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3360             try:
-> 3361                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3362             except KeyError as err:

~\scoop\apps\anaconda3\2021.05\lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

~\scoop\apps\anaconda3\2021.05\lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 0

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-266-55f0006d1f02> in <module>
----> 1 groups= df_test.groupby(by=["UnitNumber", "Date"]).apply(somefunction)

~\scoop\apps\anaconda3\2021.05\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py in apply(self, func, *args, **kwargs)
   1251         with option_context("mode.chained_assignment", None):
   1252             try:
-> 1253                 result = self._python_apply_general(f, self._selected_obj)
   1254             except TypeError:
   1255                 # gh-20949

~\scoop\apps\anaconda3\2021.05\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py in _python_apply_general(self, f, data)
   1285             data after applying f
   1286         """
-> 1287         keys, values, mutated = self.grouper.apply(f, data, self.axis)
   1288 
   1289         return self._wrap_applied_output(

~\scoop\apps\anaconda3\2021.05\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\ops.py in apply(self, f, data, axis)
    818             # group might be modified
    819             group_axes = group.axes
--> 820             res = f(group)
    821             if not _is_indexed_like(res, group_axes, axis):
    822                 mutated = True

<ipython-input-264-c99a31bdd0cf> in somefunction(group)
      1 def somefunction(group):
----> 2      print(group["Date"][0]) # <- This line causes the problem...
      3  #   print("hello")
      4      return group

~\scoop\apps\anaconda3\2021.05\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in __getitem__(self, key)
    940 
    941         elif key_is_scalar:
--> 942             return self._get_value(key)
    943 
    944         if is_hashable(key):

~\scoop\apps\anaconda3\2021.05\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in _get_value(self, label, takeable)
   1049 
   1050         # Similar to Index.get_value, but we do not fall back to positional
-> 1051         loc = self.index.get_loc(label)
   1052         return self.index._get_values_for_loc(self, loc, label)
   1053 

~\scoop\apps\anaconda3\2021.05\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3361                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3362             except KeyError as err:
-> 3363                 raise KeyError(key) from err
   3364 
   3365         if is_scalar(key) and isna(key) and not self.hasnans:

KeyError: 0
```

Comment: Can you add the exact error message to your question

Comment: Ok, it really is specifically the `[0]`.  I have very little experience with `pandas`, so I'm not sure how `DataFrameGroupBy` objects are meant to be accessed.  I'd suggest doing some inspection of the `group` at the start of your function to check what keys are available etc.  It will probably be something simple, but I don't know what.